# iphone: what libraries or APIs need to be used for CPU , RAM usage in iPhone

Tags: iphone, cpu-usage, ram

I am pretty new to iphone development, can any body guide me through with some APIs and libraries which be used for:

1. RAM usage
2. CPU usage

in iPhone

need to do something like [this app](http://www.digimoz.com/how-to-monitor-cpu-ram-and-battery-usage-of-your-iphone/)

Answer (score 0):

For Battery usage you can implement this notification

```
UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification
```

I am not sure about CPU and Ram usage.